# Passport user.id is different from database _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am trying to retrive the user id from the req.user.id from passport, but everytime i start a session the user.id changes. How can i get the current user id that matches the user id that is in the data base

I tried changing serialize settings in passport and well as droppin the user collection in mongodb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.